# Load Data File Powershell is missing the terminator

Tags: mysql, powershell

Trying to run the following:

```
run-MySQLQuery -ConnectionString "Server=192.168.0.1;Uid=powershell;Pwd=password;database=table;" -Query " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'U://CSV-Replaced-Output//zzz_test_load.csv' INTO TABLE sample_temp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' Ignore 1 Lines (@Title,@Location,@Company,@Url, @Description, @SourceType) set Title=@Title,Location=@Location,Company=@Company,url=@url,description=@description;";
```

Its failing with the error "is missing the terminator: '." in powershell

please can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The escape character in PowerShell interpolated strings is a backtick, not a backslash. The string argument to the **-Query** parameter ends with `ENCLOSED BY \"`, and is followed by the single-quoted string `' LINES TERMINATED BY '`, then `\r\n`, then a single-quoted string that is never terminated.

Change `\"` to `` `" ``.

Or, if for some reason the `"` needs to be escaped with a backslash for reasons that are internal to the **Run-MySQLQuery** function, then the problem is that you're not escaping it for the shell. In that case, change `\"` to `` \`" `` (first escaping the double-quote for the shell, then passing a string with a backslash-escaped double-quote to the function).

Comment: Hi thanks but this then causes a mysql error how can i make it just affect powershell and not the mysql query?

Comment: It's not clear what "this" refers to, since I gave you two options to used in different cases. Which one did you try and what was the MySQL error? What would the query look like if you were working with MySQL directly, i.e. ***if PowerShell were not involved***? Would you still have the backslash in there?

Comment: Sorry. I get the following: Could not run MySQL Query Exception calling "Fill" with "2" argument(s): "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

Comment: This is while using \`" or `" neither change the above error. The same sql query works fine directly into mysql so the query is not the problem.

Comment: Also other sql querys i can run just not the above Load Data File sql query via powershell.

Comment: To avoid miscommunication, rather than just describing what you're doing, please post the *actual query* that you say "works fine directly into mysql", verbatim. That way I don't need to infer what I think you're trying to quote for PowerShell purposes and what you want the actual query sent to MySQL to look like.